# How does the page size work in nested OData query?

Tags: rest, odata, expand

Let's say we want to execute following odata query:

```
api/accounts?$expand=contacts
```

Suppose that we have 3 accounts (for ex. a1, a2, a3) and 3 contacts per account.
So if we have define "***odata.maxpagesize=2***" and execute above query, what will it result according to OData standards.

**Option-1**

```
    a1
     - c11
     - c12
     - (odata.nextlink for c13)
    
    a2
     - c21
     - c22
     - (odata.nextlink for c23) 
   (odata.nextlink for a3)
```

**Option-2**

```
    a1
     - c11
     - c12
     - (odata.nextlink for c13)
   (odata.nextlink for a2, a3)
```

For ***pagesize=2*** it might look easy, but assume that ***pagesize=5000***, then will it return:

**Option-1**
5000 accounts and nested 5000 contacts for each account. So, it will have 25,000,000 records from that viewpoint.

**Option-2**
1 account and nested 5000 contacts for that account. So, it will have 5000 records from that viewpoint.

-------- UPDATE-2 -------------------------

We were just slightly hesitant for Option-1 as user can query multiple expands and it can lead to too large result size.
For ex, if user queries:
`accounts?$expand=contacts($expand=callHistory)`

So, considering option-1 with maxPageSize of 100, if we return records till maxPage Size at all nested levels then it will return
100(accounts) * 100(contacts per account) * 100(call logs per contact) = **1 million entities**.

And number of records will grow exponentially if user uses $expand at further nested levels. Please let me know if my analysis is correct.

On the other hand, **Option-2** can be close to what you suggest. Here we'll count even nested results and check if entity count is exceeding page-size. So, after that we can return nextlink wherever applicable.

It would be great if you can re-validate our approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

Either option is technically compliant with the spec. MaxPageSize is a preference (i.e., a hint to the service) and the service is allowed to return more/less, as long as it correctly returns nextLinks for incomplete collections.

So, for example, a service could also look at maxpageSize of 5000 and decide to return the first 1000 parents with up to 5 nested results each. Or, it could ignore maxpagesize entirely and return 200 parents with only next links for nested resources. Or...

I think the best consumer experience is something closer to option 1, where the service returns some a's (less than or equal to maxpagesize, perhaps based on number/level of nested results), each with some b's (again, perhaps based on the number/level of nested results, up to maxpagesize.)

Not sure if that helps?

---Response to Update 2---
Yes; your analysis is correct. And, it's more complicated than that -- the user could $expand multiple properties at each level, so you would either end up having pagesize by the number of $expanded properties at each level or you would have to decide how you divided the pagesize requested results across all of the $expanded collections at each level.

As I say, option-2 is valid, and probably easy to implement (just read up to the first pagesize records and then stop), it just might not be as friendly to a consumer that is trying to get a sense of the data (i.e., in a visual display) and then drill in where appropriate.

It kinda depends on the consumption scenario. Option 2 optimizes for only doing paging if there are more total records requested than maxpagesize, but (in the extreme) the first page of results is not very representative.

On the other hand, if the goal is for someone to view/browse through the data, drilling in where appropriate, then limiting nested collections based on some static value (say, the first 5 records of each nested collection) and then using maxpagesize to limit either the top level records or the total count of records would probably be more user-friendly. The only disadvantage would be that you might introduce paging for nested collections even when the full result was less than maxpagesize).

You also might want to consider which is more efficient to implement. For example, if you are building a query to get data from an underlying store, it may be more efficient to request a fixed maximum number of records for each nested collection, rather than requesting all of the data for nested collections and then throwing the rest away once you've read as much as you need.

Again, keep in mind that the calculation doesn't have to be exact. maxpagesize is just a hint to the service. The service is not required to return exactly that count, so don't get too bogged down on trying to exactly calculate how many records will be returned.

Personal preference: If I had potentially large nested results I would probably lean towards limiting them based on some static value. It makes the results more predictable and uniform, and provides a better representation of the data.